# Use return back()->withInput(); after a new view is returned with a link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to first post my form to my method that returns a view to preview the post that has been done. When you get to the new view of the preview i want to be able to use a link to go back to the previous page with all form inputs already filled in.

I have tried doing this with setting another url and route to the link where the route triggers a method in my controller with the return back() call. This does not seem to work and i guess it is because it is outside my method with the $request.

So i am wondering how it would be possible to achieve what i want to do. Im using Laravel 5.5

Here is my current code:

After the form is posted, you are sent to this method:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $preview = new Preview();
    $preview->post_title = $request->title;
    $preview->save();
    $previewData = Preview::latest('id')->first();
    return view('pages.preview_ad')->with('previewData', $previewData);
}
```

In the 'preview_ad' view, i want to have a link that routes to another method that triggers

```
return back()->withInput();
```

Although when i try to do this with the code below, it does not return the previous page with the inputs which the code above should. It works properly if i run it inside the 'store' method above, but not in the other method.

```
Route::get('/Skapa-annons/Tillbaka', 'PreviewsController@go_back');
```

-

```
public function go_back()
{
    return back()->withInput();
}
```

Comment: Can you describe it cleaner what exactly are you doing? What is the reason to go back? And when you go back should that data be in the Form input fields or what?

Comment: Yes the data should be back, that is what withInput does, and i want to go back if the user want to make changes to his form, therefor a preview is shown. @lewis4u

Comment: @lewis4u Ah yes, im just stupid right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already saving the Preview into DB with that store method, so the data is already in DB. Then simply create an edit form and after submit redirect the user to that edit view and the user can easily change data if needed.

Answer (score 0):

set your desired values in session then redirect to your desired route and get your session value

```
return redirect()->route('products');
```